# Bad inspector exception in chrome selenium

Tags: java

Has anyone handled a bad inspector exception ? One quick turnaround is by using Firefox but does any one know a way around chrome

Answer (score -1):

This is usually a [problem on chromedrive](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8415).
You can fork chromedrive and add a fix.